# Canonical inclusion from $S^1\to\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I come across the phrase, "let $i:S^1\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be the canonical inclusion of $S^1$ as the unit circle," a lot in the literature. I am just wondering what this map $i$ actually is.

> Is $i(x)=(\cos(2\pi x),\sin(2\pi x))$, where $S^1=[0,1]/\sim$ where $0\sim 1$?

Comment: $S^{1}= \{ (x,\,y)\;\vert\;x^{2}+y^{2}=1\}$.

Comment: Whenever $X$ is a subset of $Y$, then one can define an inclusion map $ i : X\to Y$, $i(x) = x$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: I am rephrasing what Arctic Char said. The inclusion map $i$ sends ($cos\theta,  sin\theta$) to ($cos\theta,  sin\theta$) for all real $t$.

Comment: $i(x,y)=(x,y)$ is the map. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

If I have two sets with  $A \subset B$ the inclusion map is the identity map $id: B \rightarrow B$ restricted to $A$. This map just takes the circle without the rest of the plane to itself surrounded by the plane. To see that your function isn't the right one we first note that it's not the identity. Secondly $\mathbb{R}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ since ordered pairs are not numbers. This means that there are no functions from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ that are inclusions.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{S}^1 = \{(x,y): x^2+y^2=1\}$ and the inclusion map is simply

$$i: \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2, \,i(x,y)=(x,y)$$ This is continuous (by the definition of the subspace topology), injective and non-surjective. (by compactness, in this case a closed map too).

The quotient space $[0,1]{/}\sim$ you describe is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$, so a "model" for the unit circle. The actual unit circle (or "$1$-sphere") is a subset of the plane.